# Disabling "Alt+Space = Non-breaking space" on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the Option-Space key combination for non-breaking spaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces)

Hi,

is there a way to disable the Option+Space key kombination on Mac OS X. It is really annoying when coding. Here are the hex char codes I get:

```
Space: 0x20
Alt+Space: 0xA0
```

When I accidentally press Option+Space, lots of programming languages complain when compiling, and its really hard to find as it displays as a normal space...

I'd appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the solution here:
[How to disable the Option-Space key combination for non-breaking spaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces)

Comment: Then delete this question, as it is duplicate