# Hidden characters inserted after pipe (|) followed by a space

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters

Very often, on my Mac, when I use the pipe (|) character followed by a space character, an invisible character will be inserted in between.

This is especially annoying when using the terminal, as it makes commands invalid.

If I type the following in iterm2, I often get the following:

```
ls | cat
zsh: command not found:  cat
```

If I hit the up-arrow-key to get my previous command, and then remove and reinsert the space between `|` and `cat`, the command will work.

When I copy paste the working and non working commands into a file, like this:

```
non-working: ls | cat
working: ls | cat
```

and open it in [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) it shows the following:

```
non-working: ls |¬†cat
working: ls | cat
```

I've also experienced the same kind of issue in SublimeText2 using the square brackets (<kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>) followed by a space. So I don't believe its an issue with iTerm2.

Comment: Related to this, is there a way to have Terminal show invisible characters, similar to how text editors show them, e.g. as a gray bullet?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happens is that you keep pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd> with the space bar, which inserts a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), known in HTML through the `&nbsp;` reference. This non-breaking space is useful in text processing where you want certain words to stick together, like the "OS" and "X" in "OS X".

Obviously, this is a unicode character (`00A0`), and therefore most of the command-line utilities will fail, such as bash seeing `_cat` (where `_` is the non-breaking space), and Hex Fiend just using a bad representation for it. Some editors on the other hand will just silently strip it out (e.g. this editor right here), while others even have a special representation for it (e.g. TextMate showing a dot instead of the blank space).

There are two solutions:

- Pay more attention to let go of the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key when pressing the space bar. By the way: It happens to me all the time too.
- Disable the combination altogether: [How to disable the Option-Space key combination for non-breaking spaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces)

Comment: This does indeed appear to be the issue. Can't believe I haven't caught this before. I guess a solution would be to remap space combined with the `⌥` modifier to a regular space character.

Comment: Is it possible to make the Terminal display nbsp as a reverse character or some sort, so you would instantly see it when you mistype?

Comment: @forthrin Good question. I don't know of any way to do that, other than messing with your locale settings such that non-ASCII characters cannot be displayed properly.