# OS X - Disable keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am having trouble with keyboard shortcuts, as referenced by this link:

http://www.tomnunamaker.com/mac-os-x-lion-keyboard-shortcuts/31277/

Basically I am using shortcuts in my WordPress editor, and to insert media I press alt-shift-m, but also prints this modified Â in my posts, which I have to delete each time. This is very annoying, so I'd like to disable keyboard shortcuts, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "~M" = noop:;
}
```

It doesn't work in some applications (like Xcode, Terminal, or Firefox) though.

You could also create a new keyboard layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).

1. Choose File > New Based on Current Input Source.
2. Remove the output of alphanumberic keys under option and option and shift. If you remove the keymaps completely, some key combinations like ⌥← and ⌥⌫ won't work.
3. Save the keyboard layout as bundle or XML to /Library/Keyboard Layouts/. Keyboard layouts in the user library can't be selected in password dialogs or the login window. The popovers shown when holding keys only work with the bundle format.
4. Log out and back in.
5. Enable the input source in System Preferences.

You can disable all other input sources by [editing the HIToolBox plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout).
To apply changes to the keylayout file, run `sudo touch /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/` and log out and back in.