# Disable the caret browsing permanently in Firefox on a Mac?

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't use the caret browsing and I want to remove F7 key function from Firefox.

Can that be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OS X - Disable keyboard shortcuts](http://superuser.com/questions/515044/os-x-disable-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That question does not apply to Firefox, just the native Apple provided apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to about:config in Firefox and search `accessibility.browsewithcaret_shortcut.enabled` change value as False.

Comment: I can confirm that it also works on Windows 