# Disable non-breaking space (Option-Space) specifically in Xcode

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, xcode

There's a pretty general solution for disabling the non-breaking space in OS X for some apps:

[How to disable the Option-Space key combination for non-breaking spaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces)

Unfortunately, Xcode is not one of them, and the solution does not work.

Any ideas on how to disable Option-Space for Xcode specifically?

I'm using a slightly customized keyboard layout, created with Ukulele; perhaps it could be used to remap that particular combination?

I'd rather not use stuff like KeyRemap4Macbook (or whatever it's called), since I've experienced a considerable, unacceptable lag during typing when using that app with some remaps.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any way of doing this, but you can edit the Key Bindings and add **alt+space** as an alternative for **tab**, for example. This way at least your code will compile without warning, and it will be easy to see where you made the mistake. It would be better to have it insert a space, but there doesn't seem to be that option.

Update: I have switched to **indent**, which doesn't actually do anything for me, which I find a better solution.

Comment: I've actually being using this solution for quite a while now - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179653/120468